# Error in TikZ pgfplots that previously compiled

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to compile the following code with no luck.
The odd thing is that it was working and then suddenly it is no more working (I edited something in the document and upgrade CSV files, but this part was untouched).

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[tight background, trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[%
    date coordinates in=x,
    scale only axis,
    ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
    grid=both,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=3cm,
    xticklabel=\day-\month,
    legend pos=north west]

    \addplot [color=myRoyalBlue,mark=x]
     table [col sep=comma,y=count, x=date] {gfx/daily.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Legend1}
    \addplot [color=classicRed,mark=*]
     table [col sep=comma,y=active, x=date] {gfx/active.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Legend2}

    \node[anchor=west] (source) at (axis cs:2014-12-10,75) {%
      Monitoring started};
    \node (destination) at (axis cs:2015-01-10,35) {};
    \draw[->] (source)--(destination);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Daily activity of \thesystem]{Daily activity of \thesystem during the collection time span.}
\label{fig:daily}
\end{figure}
```

The two CSVs have the following format.

daily.csv

```
date,count
2014-11-17,5
2014-11-18,0
2014-11-19,0
2014-11-20,1
```

active.csv

```
date,active
Jan 24,49
Jan 25,46
Jan 26,44
Jan 27,47
```

The result was something similar to this:
[image: Example image]

**Moreover, Latex doesn't point me to these lines for the errors, but elsewhere. *If I comment this code, everything works.***

The errors I obtained are the following:

> /Chapters/Chapter05.tex:177: Missing number, treated as zero. [...
> \addplot [color=myRoyalBlue,error bars/.]
>
> ./Chapters/Chapter05.tex:177: Missing number, treated as zero. [...
> \addplot [color=myRoyalBlue,error bars/.]
>
> ./Chapters/Chapter05.tex:177: Missing number, treated as zero. [...
> \addplot [color=myRoyalBlue,error bars/.]
>
> ./Chapters/Chapter05.tex:177: Missing } inserted. [... \addplot
> [color=myRoyalBlue,error bars/.]
>
> ./Chapters/Chapter05.tex:177: Argument of \pgfcalendar@datetojulian has an extra }. [... \addplot
> [color=myRoyalBlue,error bars/.]

So it seems I'm missing something to close.

**UPDATE**: isolating the graph, I get the following error:

> TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \pgfcalendar@datetojulia12-10,75) {Monitoring started};\node (destination) at (axis cs:2015-0

**UPDATE #2**: and commenting out the nodes part, I get the following truncated error:

> TeX STOPPED: gfplots@calender@ZEROSHIFT \relax \ifx \pgfplotstemptime \pgfutil@empty \ETC.! File ended while scanning use of \pgfcalendar@datetojuliaRunaway argu

Comment: We need a [minimal (not) working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the error message. Add the document class and required packages, but get rid of everything (colors, data files, etc.) that does not affect the appearance of the error message.

Comment: @PaulGessler: I update the post with an isolated error. Now I work on the MWE.

Comment: There is still no MWE: please consult the link I posted above. It should be a complete code that we can copy, paste, and compile to reproduce the error without needing to change any code.

Comment: From what I understand, pgfplots attempts to parse "Jan 24" as a date. However, the expected date format is YYYY-MM-DD; everything else is invalid input. To my knowledge, this should never have worked; no version of pgfplots/pgf has accepted such a date format. Are you sure there has been no change to this code? There might have been changes to the `axis cs` notation; perhaps you need to add curly braces around which were unnecessary previously... ?

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave no complete MWE and you given datas were not complete I had a little bit to guess how your code could look.

Nevertheless the following MWE compiles with a current MiKTeX 2.9 without an error message nor a warning (the shown two warnings throws `filecontent` I have used to include both csv files to the MWE).

As you can see I changed the dates in your active table. With your original version there are three errors and no pdf (your original file is included, but I commented it. If you want to test, uncoment it and comment the other version).

At last I changed the dates a little bit to get a similar picture you showed.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-daily.csv}
date,count
2014-11-17,5
2014-11-18,0
2014-11-19,0
2014-11-20,1
\end{filecontents*}

%\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-active.csv}
%date,active
%Jan 24,49
%Jan 25,46
%Jan 26,44
%Jan 27,47
%\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-active.csv}
date,active
2014-11-24,49
2014-11-25,46
2014-11-26,44
2014-11-27,47
\end{filecontents*}


%\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,backgrounds,pgfplots.dateplot}%fpu calendar


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[tight background, trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[%
    date coordinates in=x,
    scale only axis,
    ytick={0,25,50,75,100},
    grid=both,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=3cm,
    xticklabel=\day-\month,
    legend pos=north west]

    \addplot [color=blue,mark=x]
     table [col sep=comma,y=count, x=date] {\jobname-daily.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Legend1}
    \addplot [color=red,mark=*]
     table [col sep=comma,y=active, x=date] {\jobname-active.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Legend2}

    \node[anchor=west] (source) at (axis cs:2014-11-20,30) {%
      Monitoring started};
    \node (destination) at (axis cs:2014-11-24,49) {};
    \draw[->] (source)--(destination);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Daily activity of thesystem]{Daily activity of thesystem during the collection time span.}
\label{fig:daily}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]